# Html/CSS/JavaScript Removing image preview onmousehold

Tags: javascript, html, css

hi the context is that I am developping a jQuery plugin for a "mousehold" event, it already exists some but they mostly trigger the callback function using intval, for this particular project, I need it to trigger on mousemove, everything was fine but I encounter an issue for images.

The effect I'm trying to reproduce is for instance when you want to drag and re-position your facebook thumbnail profile picture.

The thing is, as you can see on the picture, when you drag the picture, it shows the images which I do not want, is there anyway to avoid that, I also do not want it because my events for mouseup/out/move doesn't trigger correctly because of that.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/sanstitrebzs.png/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using jQuery:

```
$("image").on("selectstart dragstart", function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
}
```

or CSS solution:

```
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
```